# Should I include the courses I taught in my resume?

Tags: resume

I've been working for 2 years already as a developer in my company, during this time I also imparted some courses on how to use tech in industry. Now that I'm looking for a new job, should I include these in my resume or it could be seen by the new company as a bad thing?

Comment: Welcome to TWP.  Good question.  In the future, you may want to wait a few days to pick a best answer, as questions without a chosen best answer tend to attract more attention

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> should I include these in my resume or it could be seen by the new
> company as a bad thing?

**Absolutely, include them.**

Make sure to include a link, if you can, so the content may be viewed by prospective employers.  If you cannot make it available online, definitely be prepared to discuss or show the course when interviewing.

Probably goes without saying, but make sure the links actually work and that the content displays as you expect.  I am making the assumption that the quality of the courses is good.

Most employers look fondly on this type of thing ( *teaching a technology* ), and I don't see any negatives to this.

Comment: That'ts a good advice, I'll do it that way, I thought maybe employers would think: "Why was this guy teaching if he is a developer?"

Comment: @Gamopo There are a lot of good things implied by teaching: You're good at what you know, you're able to explain these concepts to people who know less than you (which also implies you'd be good at mentoring junior co-workers), real interest in your area of expertise (you likely did at least some work for this on your own time), etc. It would especially help you if you applied for roles in Developer Relations, Training, and things directly involving teaching but it's all good stuff in general.

Comment: Agreed : there’s absolutely NO downside to include your teachings. No sane company/recruiter would look down on that. And those who do… well, I’d strongly advise against working for them !

Answer (score 4):

*"Bah, Humbug!"*  "Dead giveaways of age?" *(These* ***kids*** *today!!")*

But seriously ... "the ability to 'do' something, yourself, is one thing, but the ability to 'teach or train'* ***someone else*** *to do it, is entirely another!"

Today, I'm extremely proud that I served for very-many as a community-college instructor, and also as a professional trainer. (And, who knows, my career isn't exactly over yet ...)

Yes! I *highlight* this in a separate section of my resume, after my summary of my most-recent jobs or engagements.

Answer (score 2):

I am not expert but I am a software developer too and I added my last course and certification that I have done , this is a plus for you because you are telling them you have more abilities and skills ,etc  if you have a youtube channel about devs you also should add it because this kind of things show them that you have great skills.